# Namespace spl_autoload problem in Wordpress admin

Tags: php, wp-admin

I am experimenting with PHP namespacing within Worpdress plugins. The plugin includes a loader file which sets up the spl_autoload functionality and then instantiates a different controller depending on whether the current page request 'is_admin()' or not.

[WP_PLUGIN_DIR]/lhes_experiment/loader.php

```
use lhes\system\controllers as sys;

set_include_path('./wp-content/plugins/lhes_experiment/' . PATH_SEPARATOR .     get_include_path());
spl_autoload_extensions(".php"); // comma-separated list
spl_autoload_register( 'spl_autoload' );

$config = array( ... );

if( is_admin() ){
   error_log( var_export( new sys\experiment( ), true ), 0 );
}else{
   error_log( var_export( new sys\experiment( ), true ), 0 );
}
```

[WP_PLUGIN_DIR]/lhes_experiment/lhes/system/controllers/experiment.php

```
namespace lhes\system\controllers;
   class experiment extends test{
      public $property;
      function __construct( ){
         $this->property = 'owls';
      }
   }
```

[WP_PLUGIN_DIR]/lhes_experiment/lhes/system/controllers/test.php

```
namespace lhes\system\controllers;
   class test{
      public $test;
      function __construct( ){
         $this->test = 'hi';
      }
   }
```

When the request is **not** and admin page, the code runs as expected and the error log shows:

```
[23-Jan-2013 12:55:27 UTC] lhes\system\controllers\experiment::__set_state(array(
   'property' => 'owls',
   'test' => 'hi',
))
```

However, when the request **is** to an admin page the exact same code does not work:

```
[23-Jan-2013 12:56:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'lhes\system\controllers\test' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\lhes_experiment\lhes\system\controllers\experiment.php on line 4
```

I've spent many an hour googling the problem but can't seem to find anything. If anyone has any ideas as to why this might be happening I would really appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `set_include_path` is wrong.

Instead use:

```
set_include_path(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
```

Tested it with your code and it works.

For reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories

Comment: @mbadger: this is because your code is setting a relative path (relative to what? when?) whereas Wyck's code is setting an absolute path that will find your classes no matter from where is it called.

Comment: @webaware: Thanks for pointing that out, setting the absolute path like Wyck pointed out did indeed sort the problem.  I am curious as to why it worked at all though. My assumption was that it would treat '.' as the server root, which it appeared to do on the front end.

Comment: Every page / post on the front end effectively runs from the root of the website, as it is routed to {root}/index.php, whereas admin pages generally run from {root}/wp-admin (or from specific plugins' folders).

Comment: Ah, of course! Much appreciated